# Date Validation Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a validation for the post in my Controller.

I have a problem about the date.

I have created in applications/libraries a MY_Form_validation.php page in which I wrote this:

```
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($date, $format);
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

Then I have created the form_validation_lang.php with

```
<?php

$lang['form_validation_valid_date'] = 'The field {field} is not a valid date';
```

While in my controller I have:

```
//load the libraries

$this->form_validation->set_rules('birthdate', 'birthdate', 'trim|required|valid_date');

 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
            var_dump($errors);
            $this->response($errors, 500); 
            return;
        }


  $person = array(
//..
'birthdate' => $this->post('birthdate'),
//...
);
```

It prints me that:

'birthdate' => 'string'

About my DB at the beginning my field was Data, and i received this error. Than I have changed to Datetime but the error is the same.

Now it's:

> `birthdate` date NOT NULL,

Now for example I'm trying to post a date like '1960-04-20' and I receive back the error:

> "birthdate": "The field birthdate is not a valid date"

I want to write in the db only the date and not the time, could be this the problem?? 
How can I do to validate date?

Thank you

Comment: Is your DB field a `Date` field and not a `Datetime`?

Comment: yes in my DB the field is Date

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Can't I use valid_date with a Date field in the DB?

Comment: No no a Date field is what you need to have don't let my comment misguide you please :) I was just making sure, that's not the issue you're having

Comment: Are you here? I have a good news. I've created the same date validation option for my website. And I figured out an issue and a solution of it.

Comment: @AksenP Yes, I have understand my problem.. I had change (i don't remember the reason) a part of my config.php file, so the library "MY_Form_validation" wasn't loaded. This is the reason why it doesn't work. After that the method that I was trying work perfectly. Anyway I'm accepting your answer to thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Jack23, yeah, I thought it was an easy issue, at least for PHP, but CodeIgniter works a little bit different. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your function with next:

```
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') { 
    $d = new DateTime($date); 
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XuKPn)**

Or with next one:

```
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') { 
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$date);   // <-- replace arguments
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/h80oq)**

[DateTime::createFromFormat() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

You need to cast this string, after success validation, into DATE datatype and only then send it into DB. Or you can write `"to_date($stringvar,$format)"` in your SQL query.

Seems like CodeIgniter doesn't likes default variables in validation options. I mean, you can't declare `$format = 'Y-m-d'` as an argument. So, it would work if you won't use it:

```
public function valid_date_dmY($str)
{    
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y',$str);    
        return $d && $d->format('d.m.Y') === $str; 
}
```

Comment: mmh I had tried it. Do you think that the problem is because in my db the field is Date and not Datetime?

Comment: @Jack23, in fact, this is a validation PHP code. And you can see it works. If you have another Date format in your DB - yes, it may raise an error. In your question you have a mistake, at least in `DateTime::createFromFormat()`

Comment: I have tried to change the field in my DB in Datetime() but the error is the same :/
Yes at the beginning I have inserted the arguments in the right places, i don't know why I have inverted xD

Comment: @Jack23, show your DB's field. Datatype and format, make custim insert with some default value.

Comment: Before to use validation I have inserted value simple like: '1960-02-25'... without problem. Now I'm trying to check the data and I have this problem. Anyway I have edited my question.

Comment: @Jack23, before inserting/sending value into DB make `var_dump($date_var);` and if it hasn't `date` as a datatype - it's a problem. I guess it's a `string`.

Comment: But If I would change this field in datatime why I receive the same error? I'm interested only to the date and not the time.

Comment: @Jack23, I don't see **var_dump()** as I asked. I don't see datatype of your column in DB and defined format to it.

Comment: Sorry man where I should put the var_dump? In the form validation? datatype is date

Comment: @Jack23, **before inserting/sending into DB**.

Comment: So after the post.. I have done but it prints me only the error about the birthdate

Comment: @Jack23,......comment inserting/sending into DB....leave only var_dump()...

Comment: @Jack23, as I guessed.

Comment: @Jack23, you need to cast this string, after success validation, into DATE datatype and only then send it into DB. Or you can write `"to_date($stringvar,$format)"` in your SQL query.

Comment: Only just last question. I should to cast this string to date, I should do before the validation, right? So I should do there? `'birthdate' => $this->post('birthdate'),` ?

Comment: @Jack23, no, validation works with string. Do it after validation. Before inserting or during it.